# Spark xml processing in a csv file

Tags: xml, apache-spark

I have a csv or tab separated file like below:

```
1001,2016-02-23,req,<xmlString><user><name>name1</name><addr>address1</addr></user></xmlString>,20.0

1002,2016-02-24,req,<xmlString><user><name>name2</name><addr>address1</addr></user></xmlString>,30.0
```

I want to read this file and convert each line into csv file (including the xml attributes) so that i can put it into hive.

LIKE THIS:

1001,2016-02-23,req,name1,address1,20.0

1002,2016-02-24,req,name2,address1,20.0

How would i do this in spark? how would i read each row and process the xml bit and generate the output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `rdd = sc.textFile(...)` will read your file with each row in tuple. To process each line, just do `rdd.map(lambda row: row.split(',')).map(lambda row: yourFilterFunction(row))`

With the new spark API you can read csv files and infer schema but I think it is good for you to hardcode this kind of code.

You should learn and read documentation before asking a question that has been asked thousands of times...